# What do you call these disco lightbulbs that shoot a lot of light in various directions?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call these disco lightbulbs that shoot a lot of light in various directions? Is there a specific word for it? I doubt that it's just called a disco light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things are often called "disco light (or lights) balls" or "disco ball lights". They are a type of disco light.

[image]